# Why Gateaux derivative is a distribuition?

Tags: distribution-theory, vector-bundles, locally-convex-spaces, gateaux-derivative

Let $E$  be a vector bundle , $E^*$ the dual bundle and $D$ a density bundle. Denote by $\Gamma(E)$ the space of section of the bundle $E$.

By definition the a distribution $\omega$ in  a vector bundle $E$ is $\omega \in\Gamma(E^*\otimes D)^\prime$ where  $\Gamma(E^*\otimes D)^\prime$ is the topological dual of $\Gamma(E^*\otimes D)$.

Now in this paper [Algebraic Structure of Classical Field Theory: Kinematics and Linearized Dynamics for Real Scalar Fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2148)  by  Romeo Brunetti, Klaus Fredenhagen, Pedro Lauridsen Ribeiro they define at page 14 the Gateaux derivative as $$F^K[\phi](\phi_1...,\phi_k)=\left<F^K[\phi],\phi_1\otimes...\otimes\phi_k\right>=\frac{d^k}{d\lambda_1...d\lambda_k }\left(\phi + \lambda_1\phi_1+...\lambda_k\phi_k\right)$$
where $<>$ denotes dual pairing and $\phi,\phi_1...,\phi_k \in\Gamma(E)  $

Now they say that $F^K[\phi]$ is a distribuition . But  $F^K[\phi]$ is not in  $\Gamma(E^*\otimes D)^\prime$ how can it be a distribution?

.
In this paper [Properties of field functionals and characterization of local functionals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01937) by Christian Brouder, Nguyen Viet Dang, Camille Laurent-Gengoux, Kasia Rejzner at page 10

they define $F^K[\phi]$ as a d distributional section on $M^k$ for a general vector bundle.

Maybe they are using $<>$ to identify $E$ with $E^*$ but I am not sure

Comment: They say that $F^{(k)}[\varphi]$ is a "distribution *density*" for fixed $\varphi.$

Comment: What is a distribuition density?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps I can find out by googling, reading and thinking.